# Проблема с массивом строк в методе. Возвращается хэшкод объекта, а не его содержимое

Tags: java

Всем доброго времени суток. Есть очень глупый вопрос уровня совсем новичка. Столкнулся с проблемой преобразования типа. Написал простой метод для убирания нулей перед числом в строке(на входе="0000001001", хочу на выходе="1001").
Для этого написал метод

```
 public static void formatNum(String str){
        String[] sup;
        sup=new String[str.length()];

        str.split("");
       for(int i=0; i<str.length();i++){
              if(sup[i]=="0")
                  sup[i]="";
              else break;

       }
        for(String s:sup)
        System.out.print(sup.toString());

       //return sup.toString();
    }
```

Но есть беда. на выходе в sout получаю код объекта в памяти, а не содержимое массива.

Путём проб понял, что проблема именно в массиве String[]. 
Как решить это и получить на выходе желаемую строку ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Причина в досадной опечатке:

```
for(String s:sup)
        System.out.print(s.toString());
```

внутри цикла нужно вызывать **s**.toString() то есть текущий элемент массива, а не сам массив

А после правки данной ошибки и запуска оказалась еще одна оплошность

```
sup = str.split("");
```

а потом вылезла еще одна ошибка - сравнение объектов по ссылке, а надо так...

```
if(sup[i].equals("0"))
```

После этого заработало...

Советую сразу писать код через тестирование, а не использовать консоль вывода и дебаг режим. 
Тесты писать легче чем код, и сразу будете проверять свои программы

Comment: `sup[i].equals("0")` можно было оставить как `==` -- java для маленьких строк создает кэш, поэтому сравнение по ссылкам сработает, но лучше приучать к equals :)

Comment: похоже что не всегда...вот я запустил код в Idea c jdk8 и у меня без этой правки данное условие не работало

Comment: Для литеральных строк так и будет, но если строки через `new String` создавались должен новый объект создаться

Comment: все так если бы оба сравниваемых объекта создавались литерально...но левая часть была создана в рамках работы метода split. Судя по всему при запуске программы фактически оператор сравнения по ссылке не сработал как ожидала семантика

Comment: Ага, такой вот забавная особенность сравнения у java -- сравнение через `==` для простых типов по значению, а для объектов выполнится проверка по ссылкам и, что не интуитивно `new String("123") == new String("123")` вернет `false`, т.к. хоть эти два объекта одинаковые по значению, но разные по ссылкам :) Поэтому, все объекты имеют метод `equals` -- для сравнения объектов по значению. Кст,  в питоне с этим получше -- оператор `==` скрытно вызывает метод сравнения значения объектов (каждый тип реализует метод `__eq__`), а для сравнения по ссылке есть оператор `is`

Comment: я не считаю лучшим вариант когда за меня кто то что то решает и додумывает. Мне вполне достаточно четкой ясности сравнение по ссылкам это сравнение по ссылкам...по значению значит по значению...Мне не хватает в Java значимых типов которые есть в C#...Но в остальном у меня нет тут притензий...Это хорошо ложиться с разностью семантики Entity и ValueObject...Entity это как раз объект с идентификатором...и только он его идентифицирует, а примитивы и значимые типы(структуры) это ValueObject, где единственное что важно это значение и идентификации они не имеют.

Comment: Спасибо большое проблема решилась, теперь понял, что объекты классов по значению надо сравнивать с помощь метода .equals("0") с sup.split("") скорее всего просто опечатка в коде, пока пытался найти ошибку сам)

Ещё раз большое спасибо

Comment: @Никита Романов. Всегда пожалуйста.Но я очень бы рекомендовал рассмотреть код предложенный gil9red. Он чище, в нем использованы хорошие практики написания понятного и поддерживаемого кода. А так же прям только начав погружаться в программирование стоит прочесть книгу "Совершенный код" это будет хорошая инвестиция в будущее

Answer (score 1):

> Написал простой метод для убирания нулей перед числом в строке(на
>   входе="0000001001", хочу на выходе="1001")

Вам нужно из массива строк составить строку, сложив все элементы.

Например:

```
    public static String formatNum(String str) {
        String[] items = str.split("");
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (items[i].equals("0")) {
                items[i] = "";
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return String.join("", items);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(formatNum("000100")); // 100
    }
```

---

**PS.**

`String.join` работает с java 8, но для ранних версий пришлось бы вручную реализовывать, например:

```
public static String join(String sep, String[] items) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            builder.append(sep);
        }
        builder.append(items[i]);
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Вы все верно написали, вы просто решили за него задачу и пользы топикстартеру, от этого мало...он не увидел где он ошибся, и в следующий раз столкнется с такой же проблемой и не сможет ее идентифицировать и исправить

Comment: @skingreek, поэтому хорошо, что вы в своем ответе все объяснили ;)